# catkin package CATKIN_DEPENDS question

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following structure.

`my_first_package` exposes its headers:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES 
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS
#  DEPENDS systemlib
)
```

`my_second_package` depends on `my_first_package`. In `my_second_package`'s CMakeLists.txt `my_first_package` is stated as `CATKIN_DEPENDS`:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES 
  CATKIN_DEPENDS my_first_package
#  DEPENDS systemlib
)
```

`my_third_package` depends on `my_second_package`. It is able to "see" headers and stuff of `my_second_package` and  `my_first_package`. However, in `my_third_package` depends's CMakeLists.txt my_second_package is !!not!! stated as `CATKIN_DEPENDS`:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES 
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS #NOTE: not set
#  DEPENDS systemlib
)
```

Now: Will `my_fourth_package` which depends on `my_third_package` be able to "see" headers and stuff of `my_first_package`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192547/catkin-package-catkin_depends-question/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, since the third package does not depend on the second it also does not get the transitive dependency on the first package.

It *might* work if all packages are installed in the same location and the include folders are all the same after installation. But you should not rely on that. In an isolated build it should not work without adding the dependency explicitly.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1